# separate linear contrasts per condition

Tags: r, lm

With this example data set

```
dat <- data.frame(sample=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14), treatment=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8), condition=factor(c("A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","B")), scores=c(2,4,3,5,6,13,41,30,30,23,24,24,10,8))
```

I predict a linear increase for `condition A` across `treatment` levels, but expect linear decrease for `condition B` across `treatment` levels.

How can I extract the parameter estimates of these linear contrasts separately for each `condition`?

I thought of creating manual contrasts and then `contrasts(dat$treatment) <- matrix(c(contr.poly(6)[,1],rep(0,8),rep(0,6),contr.poly(8)[,1]*-1), ncol=2)`

but this won't work since `treatment` isn't a factor.

Comment: Is there a reason you wouldn't just fit a linear model with an interaction term like `lm(scores~treatment*condition)` and extract the parameter values from that using `summary()`?

Comment: @mkt, I'd eventually like to use custom contrasts that are more complex than simple linear ones. My question is just to understand how I can set up manual contrasts.

Comment: [This link](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/contrasts+r) will show you all questions tagged [tag:contrasts] and [tag:r]. One of them might solve your problem.